# How to stream WebRTC audio to Icecast server?

Tags: webrtc, icecast

How can i make an audio stream captured in browser using WebRTC to be streamed live via icecast/shoutcast protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use liquidsoap + webcaster.js:

https://github.com/webcast/webcaster

Comment: Thank you, Alex! As I see, it uses WebSockets to pack a data. Did you mentioned, how stable it is, how low latencies are? Is it possible to use WebRTC as an audio transport itself, probably with some kind of WebRTC->Icecast/shoutcast transcoder in the middle? Thank You again.

Comment: Using it right now and it is pretty table, latency is about the same as if broadcast from external program like SamBroadcaster.
It is impossible to send data directly to icecast via WebSockets, but using `liquidsoap` in the middle allow that, basically the data flow is: `WebSocket` -> `liquidsoap` -> `Icecast`

Comment: This answer is wrong - Webcaster.js has nothing to do with WebRTC. It uses websockets, not WebRTC.